# After done the version changes still not opening the index.html files and not able to generate multiple jmx file report in one go

Tags: html, jmeter

After done the version changes still not opening the index.html files and not able to generate multiple jmx file report in one go.
It should open the report as dashboard. I am not able to open the charts and graphs.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should [properly ask your question](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) as it is not clear what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve.

If you're running multiple [.jmx test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) at the same time you should have multiple [.jtl results files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) from different tests executions.

Once your tests are done you can combine theset .jtl files into one by either your operating system utilities or using [Merge Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager))

Then you can [generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard from that single .jtl results file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) like:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/file.jtl -o /path/to/dashboard
```